# As to unbalanced design sample data,do we need to check variance homogeneity as precondition of two way anova?

Tags: anova, variance, unbalanced-classes, manova

For the balanced design data,I know variance homogeneity among each cell is the requirement of two way anova.
As to unbalanced design data,do we need to check the variance homogeneity of each cell?
If yes,which test should be used when data is variance Inhomogeneity?

Answer (score 1):

(a) In many ANOVA designs there will not be enough replications for each 'cell' (combination of levels of the two factors) to do a useful test of homogeneity of variances. Do the ANOVA, find the residuals, and plot the them against data values. You can see serious heteroscedastisity visually, to warn you that P-values may not be correct.

(b) What to do in case of heteroscedasticity? Suppose you have $a$ levels of Factor A, $b$ levels of Factor B, and $r$ replications per cell, for $N=abr$ observations altogether.

- First, see if a (log or power) transformation of the $N$ observations can moderate the problem. [A drawback of transformations is that they make it harder to discuss level-to-level differences.]
- If not, do a rank transformation, replacing
  each of the $N$ observations by its rank $1$ through $N$ among all observations. Then do an ANOVA on ranks. [Ranks will typically have variances more nearly equal than for
  the original $Y_{ijk}$ because ranks must lie between $1$ and $N.]$
- As a last resort (extreme, intractable heteroscedasticity), turn the 2-way ANOVA with $ab$ cells into a one-way ANOVA with $ab$ levels. Use 
  Satterthwaite one-way ANOVA (implemented in R's `oneway.test`), which does not assume equal group variances. If the F-test rejects, then explore *ad hoc* relationships of the original two-way ANOVA that are crucial to the purpose of the study. [I have had to do this a few times in designs with large $r,$ sometimes unbalanced. Messy, but
  at least in one instance, well worth the trouble.]

A major difficulty with severely different variances can be F-ratios too large, P-values too small, and thus false discovery. 
If you are lucky, ANOVA results from the bullet points above will be somewhat the same as for the original ANOVA with unmodified data.

In a report for non-statistical audiences, it may be best to show the original ANOVA table, remarking on any P-values that can no longer be taken seriously, and briefly mentioning specific instances of unequal variances.

Comment: I always has 5000+ sample,average 500 per cell.Is that enough to test variance homogeneity?

Comment: For unbalanced design data,do we need to check the variance homogeneity of each cell when two way anova?